# How to make boost::exponential_distribution work?

Tags: c++, boost, random

I have been playing with Boost.Random for a day now, and while `boost::uniform_int_distribution<>` works well, I am having trouble with `boost::exponential_distribution<>`.

A simple program is worth a thousand words:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/exponential_distribution.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::mt19937 gen;
  boost::exponential_distribution<> dis;
  std::cout << dis(gen) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with Clang 3.0, using Boost 1.39.1 (no, I cannot upgrade Boost).

The output is invariably the same: `nan`.

I could not find any reported issue so I guess it's me not using the library correctly... Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: The code gave me `1.68591` on latest boost (1.48) with gcc (sorry, can't help with anything else though).

Comment: @Jesse: Thanks for testing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a random number `r`, uniformly distributed on [0,1),  `-log(r)` is distributed on (0,infinity) with the distribution `exp(-x)`.
The former is `boost::uniform_01()`.

If you need a distribution `p exp(-px)`, then it's `-(1/p)log(r)`.

In both cases here `log(x)` is a natural log (base `e`).

UPD: Using `boost::variate_generator` seems to work for me (boost 1.43):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<boost/random.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::mt19937 rng(11u); 
  boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937&, boost::exponential_distribution<> > rndm(rng, boost::exponential_distribution<>()) ;
  std::cout<<rndm()<<"\n";
}
```

I did not check the distribution though.

Comment: I confirm that going through a `variate_generator` works, thanks for the tip. Now if only I understood what the difference is...

Comment: I've no idea why it is so :-(. I personally would use the transformation from my answer and be done with it. By the way, you surely know that in your code piece you're not seeding the generator?

Comment: I used your trick for now, I am looking at the `variate_generator` source code. As for not seeding, this is so that I can produce identical output on every run while fine tuning my algorithm, once I am done I'll use some time-based seed or something.

Comment: I could not find the difference, your solution work so it will have to do. Thanks :)